# Rails app for multiple physical locations, with aggregation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm writing a Rails app for a small property management company. The
app will be used by property managers on-site at various apartment
complexes, and by office managers at the central office. Property
managers will be able to retrieve and update data for their site, and
office managers will be able to do so far any site, but also be able
to run reports over the whole aggregation.

I'm wondering what the most pain-free way of implementing this is. So
far, the best I can think of is to ensure that every model
`:belongs_to` a site, so every Tenant, Apartment, etc., will have a
`site_id` fk. As far as I can tell, this is the simplest,
conceptually, to implement. The downside is that, for any hand-written
or -tuned query I write, I'll need to remember to add an `"and site_id
= ?"` clause, and I'm afraid I'll forget to at some important point. (**EDIT:** as meagar points out, I shouldn't need to write custom sql, but the question remains: what will I need to add so that I can filter the results by user, and is it something I would need to add to every controller, or at a different level of the application?)

Alternately, I can have multiple schemas/databases, but I don't know
how well that would work, given that office managers need to be able to
query and run reports over the system as a whole.

What is the "Rails way" to work with either of these options (if such exists) or is there another way altogether?

Comment: You should never have to worry about remembering to add a `and site_id = ?` clause, because you should never be manually writing such a clause. Your queries should *already* be scoped to a specific site. You should have a `Site` model. That should be your entry point to loading other types of models from your database.

Comment: meagar, when you say Site will be the entry point, do you mean that every other model will `belongs_to` it, or is that another concept that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: Every other model will either belong directly to a site, or belong indirectly to a site via other associations, yes.

Comment: To clarify the sql part of the question: even if I don't write queries, site managers should only see their location, but the central office should be able to aggregate data. Will I need to add something to, say, every controller to filter out sites based on the user? Or is there a cleaner way? (There are other on-site employees, as well as managers who travel between properties, so Users-Sites is a many-to-many relationship.)